# Getting Vowels from a String and printing them in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I've just started learning Haskell and I'm a bit stuck.

https://gyazo.com/b70aee3b5a031a6d65ea2fe993ea0824

I've made an attempt at it and I don't really know how to get my head around where I'm going wrong.

```
vowels :: String -> String
vowels [] = []
vowels xs = [] ==  [ x | x <- vowels , x == "a" || x == "e" || x == "i" || x == "o" ||  x == "u" ]
```

Comment: `filter (flip elem "aeiou")`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### First of all

you're almost there

```
vowels xs = [ x | x <- xs , x == 'a' ||
                            x == 'e' ||
                            x == 'i' ||
                            x == 'o' ||
                            x == 'u' ]
```

### But what is the actual error?

1. you were using the function as an input to your list
2. `String` litterals are surrounded by `"` where `Char` litterals have `'` and internally `String`s in Haskell are just `[Char]` so you need to use characters.

But haskell is known for conciseness and expressivity - list comprehensions are a nice way but can we do better?

### yes we can!

What you actually, do is implement a `filter`, so let us analyze what you are filtering - vowels, so let us extract that part:

```
isVowel x = x == 'a' || ... || x == 'u'
```

well this is still not elegant, but there is a function called `elem` that checks whether something is contained in a list.

```
isVowel x = x `elem` ['a','e','i','o','u']
```

and knowing that `String` = `[Char]` we can rewrite that (using so called backtick-syntax which allows to use functions of 2 parameters as an infix function)

```
isVowel :: Char -> Bool
isVowel x = x `elem` "aeiou"
```

then coming back to the original problem now that we have a function telling us what a vowel is...

```
vowel :: String -> String
vowel = filter isVowel
```

now you might be interested where is the `xs` - well since haskell has a great type system it can derive that there is one parameter missing on both sides of the `=` sign, you don't need to write that yourself (this style is called pointfree).

Comment: I've got it now thanks. Yeah I'm aware that there are better ways to go about doing this but I'm just using list comprehensions just to answer this question.